# Как исправить ошибку 'argument out of range' для библиотеки pyshp?

Tags: python, pyshp

У меня есть код.

```
w = shapefile.Writer(f'shapefiles/test/{final}')
w.autoBalance = 1
w.field('point_1','C')
w.autoBalance = 1

with open(f'{final}_long_double.txt', 'r') as long:
    for i in long:
            i_1, i_2 = i.split()
            with open(f'{final}_short_double.txt', 'r') as short:
                for k in short:
                    k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                    value = [[[float(i_1),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_2)],[float(i_1),float(k_2)]]]
#                     row_str = f'{i_1}', f'{k_1}', f'{i_2}', f'{k_2}'
                    w.poly(value)
                    w.record()
w.close()
```

Эта библиотека - pyshp. Вот ссылка на документацию: https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/
Код отрабатывает хорошо и записывает данные в нужные мне файлы. 
Но, когда длинна файла `.shp` достигает 4.29 GB, у меня код вылетает с ошибкою `argument out of range`. 
Т. е. если я записываю данные в размере меньше 4.29 Gb, то все работает.
Ошибка возникает на windows и ubuntu. Использую NTFS.

Вот полный код ошибки:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-707914cf4c31> in <module>
     15                     value = [[[float(i_1),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_1)],[float(i_2),float(k_2)],[float(i_1),float(k_2)]]]
     16 #                     row_str = f'{i_1}', f'{k_1}', f'{i_2}', f'{k_2}'
---> 17                     w.poly(value)
     18                     w.record()
     19 w.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in poly(self, polys)
   1693         If some of the polygons are holes, these must run in a counterclockwise direction."""
   1694         shapeType = POLYGON
-> 1695         self._shapeparts(parts=polys, shapeType=shapeType)
   1696 
   1697     def polym(self, polys):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in _shapeparts(self, parts, shapeType)
   1758                 polyShape.points.append(point)
   1759         # write the shape
-> 1760         self.shape(polyShape)
   1761 
   1762     def field(self, name, fieldType="C", size="50", decimal=0):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in shape(self, s)
   1351         # Write to file
   1352         offset,length = self.__shpRecord(s)
-> 1353         self.__shxRecord(offset, length)
   1354 
   1355     def __shpRecord(self, s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in __shxRecord(self, offset, length)
   1499          """Writes the shx records."""
   1500          f = self.__getFileObj(self.shx)
-> 1501          f.write(pack(">i", offset // 2))
   1502          f.write(pack(">i", length))
   1503 

error: argument out of range
```

Я не могу понять, почему возникает ошибка: из-за размера файла или по какой-то другой причине? 
Как ее испрвить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще само устройство шейп-файлов не предполагает таких размеров. Т.к. такой формат основан на устаревших `DBF-таблицах`, то и общий размер хранимой геометрии **не должен быть больше 2 GB**. [Про shp-файлы](https://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/what-is-a-shapefile.htm).

По опыту работы с ArcGIS могу сказать, что записать файл > 2GB технически возможно, но настольное ПО (ArcGIS PRO, QGIS и т.д.) либо откажется его читать, либо будет делать это с ошибками.

Лучше всего выберите другой формат хранения геометрии (класс пространственных объектов в [БД .gdb](https://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases.htm), БД [PostGIS](https://postgis.net)). Или разбейте свою информацию на блоки и запишите в отдельные `.shp-файлы` или `geoJSON`.